# 2016 Moderator Election Q&A - Questionnaire

Tags: discussion, election

In connection with the moderator elections, we are holding a Q&A thread for the candidates. Questions proposed [in an earlier thread](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/621/2016-moderator-election-qa-question-collection) have been compiled into this one, which shall now serve as the space for the candidates to provide their answers.

As a candidate, your job is simple - post an answer to this question, citing each of the questions and then post your answer to each question given in that same answer. For your convenience, I will include all of the questions in quote format with a break in between each, suitable for you to insert your answers. Just [copy the whole thing after the first set of three dashes](https://networkengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/58df2347-7c29-4236-a524-3961d11d08c0/view-source). Oh, and please consider putting your name at the top of your post so that readers will know who you are before they finish reading everything you have written.

Once all the answers have been compiled, this will serve as a transcript for voters to view the thoughts of their candidates, and will be appropriately linked in the Election page.

Good luck to all of the candidates!

---

> 1. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
> 2. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
> 3. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
> 4. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
> 5. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 2):

**Ron Maupin**

> 1. How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
>
>    *I would leave a comment for the user(s) involved, and, if necessary, remove the arguments/flagged comments, offering to discuss it in Chat, Meta, or privately, as the user(s) desires. I would stress the value of the user's participation, and I would explain the problem, asking the user to please moderate comments and take disagreements to Chat or Meta, and point out that one principle of SE is to be nice, and everyone needs to get along.*
> 2. How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?
>
>    *I would discuss it with the moderator, who may have a very different understanding of the situation. I would strive to understand the other position, and I would share my thinking. I hope that we would be able to come to an understanding, but I would not override another moderator.*
> 3. In your opinion, what do moderators do?
>
>    *I think the primary job of a moderator on a community modrated site, like Network Engineering, is to keep things running smoothly, and to help the site keep focus on what the community wants for the site. If the community decides to move in a different direction for something, a moderator should help to ease that transition. Moderators need to respond to the community members in Meta, Chat, flags, and reviews. Part of the job entails handling things which only moderators can do, but actions by moderators are binding, so careful thought is required before action is taken, and a moderator should err on the side of caution. Moderation should be as unobtrusive as possible, while remaining effective.*
> 4. A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
>
>    *I have no problem with that at all.*
> 5. In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?
>
>    *I don't think it's about making me more effective than having the reputation. The community needs moderators to function smoothly, and it's something I have volunteered to do to help the community.*

Comment: Your track record shows that you have no problem censoring everything that does not fit your taste. NE does not need censorship.

Comment: Indeed I am surprised someone would put that much effort into censoring a SE community without financial benefits....must be too much ego... I have no problem with Ron shifting his focus on destroying other SE sites...

Comment: @sdaffa23fdsf I have asked you elsewhere on meta to back up your "accusations" and you continue to just throw around negative comments without either (a) backing up your assertions or (b) providing any feedback that can help to improve anything on the site. These comments are textbook examples of non-constructive comments. If this were a playground, I would simply classify your actions on meta as those of a bully who isn't getting his way. Please try to be more constructive in future posts.